# How to stop an image from stretching within a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, stretching

I have a `UIImageView` where I have set the frame size to `x = 0, y = 0, width = 404, height = 712`.
In my project, I need to change the image in `UIImageView` dynamically.

I am using this code to change the image:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting-image.png"];
```

The problem is, when the `*.png` image size is smaller than the `UIImageView` frame size, the image stretches. I don't want it to stretch. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can use

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Swift 3:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Or `UIViewContentModeCenter` / `.center`, or any of the other modes described in [the UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but using mode aspect fit make some image's position too below, so i change it into top left mode, thank you for suggesting me to using it, finally, i've got the answer :)

Answer (score 12):

Setting clipsToBounds in combination with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit contentMode was what did the trick for me. Hope that helps someone!

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: "clipsToBounds" checkmarked & "contentMode" as "AspectFill" on the Storyboard worked for me in Xcode 8

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`contentMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW99) property. You probably want either `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeCenter`.

Answer (score 4):

Change the UIImage's Mode from 'scale to fill' to 'Center' within the interface builder. Make sure your image is the exact size you need.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to set CGSize as your image width and hight so image will not stretch and it will arrange at the middle of imageview.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToFillSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat scale = MAX(size.width/image.size.width, size.height/image.size.height);
    CGFloat width = image.size.width * scale;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height * scale;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((size.width - width)/2.0f,
                                  (size.height - height)/2.0f,
                                  width,
                                  height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for Swift 3:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the contentMode, e.g.:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to use original size of image** - without any stretching

- Just change the UIImage's Mode from `scale to fill` to `Aspect Fit` within the interface builder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your `UIImageView`

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

You won't get any space and with scale preserved. However, some part of the image will be clipped off.

If you use the following:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

There will be some empty space, but scale is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

still stretch when image is bigger than imageivew

swift

```
    let qCodeImage = UIImage(named: "qcode-placeholder.png")!      
    let qCodeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cardView.frame)-30, CGRectGetWidth(cardView.frame)-30))
    qCodeImageView.image = qCodeImage
    qCodeImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    qCodeImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    qCodeImageView.center = cardView.center
```