# Center & Aspect Fit Image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

Currently I can not set 2 content modes at the same time it seems. But I want the image both scaled and centered. How do I accomplish this?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *windowOut;

self.windowOut.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.windowOut.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;

UIImage *face = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face.png"];

UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.windowOut.frame];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

[imageView setImage:face];
[self.windowOut addSubview:imageView];
```

This image is the result with the code above:
[image]

This image is the result when  "imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
" is commented out:
[image]

EDIT:
This image is the result when I comment out both contentModes:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` center the image anyway?

Comment: nope it moves about %10 right for some weird reason

Comment: Where/when are you assigning the image? Have you checked that the `self.windowOut.frame` is what you expect?

Comment: `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` is scaled and centered _within the image view_. However, if you place the image view in some weird place, then of course the image it contains will also appear in that weird place.

Comment: I am pulling the image from the photo library. the frame is as I expect. I set the view in the storyboard. what do you mean some weird place? I have no weird places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not centered is here:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.windowOut.frame];

[self.windowOut addSubview:imageView];
```

That works only when `windowOut` happens to be located at (0/0). 
`.frame` gives the frame in its superview's coordinate system. If `windowOut` is located at, let's say (20/20) within its superview (self.view?) then `imageView` will be located at **(40,40)**.

Use `bounds` instead. That is the same but within its own coordinate system.

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.windowOut.bounds];
[self.windowOut addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Your 3rd image is just proving evidence. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`will do.

Comment: your code works perfect for the simulator but when I tested this on the device, it looks like the 3rd image but centered. 
what could be the problem?

Comment: When you observe strange variations between simulator and device then a) delete the app from the simulator, b) delete the app from the device, c) clean and rebuild.

Comment: The problem seems to be weirder. Pics downloaded or saved are showing up correctly. Pics that are taken by my iphone camera are not scaling correctly.

Comment: Probably it is the size. Camera pictures are bigger than those which fit on a website and may have been downloaded. If it is the size then go for a different content mode.

Comment: this seems to be the answer for the device large image problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485975/uiimageview-image-stretched-even-though-contentmode-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspe

Answer (score 0):

If the imageView is set to the same frame as its superview, and the content mode is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, then it should be centered by definition. Good luck!

Comment: Just curious, did you try not setting any content mode, in other words, leaving the default content mode?

Comment: yes I think the problem is not because of the content mode it seems. I added the frame after, now I see that the original image also had a centering problem for some reason. I edited the post