# UIImage should not stretched inside the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

[image: Image size is 480X360]

I am using the `UIImageView` in my xib. App is designed for multi device without auto layout. It means I am using autoresizing.What I want to do is, only my `UIImageView` should autoresize not my Image inside the `UIImageView`, but unfortunately my image also getting stretched with `UIImageView`. I have tried the different ways but could not get success. Changed the content mode also but didn't work for me.

Comment: It is not possible. UIImage will be stretched according to size of UIImageView.

Comment: @ iPhone any tricky solution , which cold help me ?

Comment: But why do you want such kind of solution?

Comment: I think you should keep the size of UIImageView fixed. No other solution as per my sight

Comment: please display your problem in screen shot @Salman

Comment: @JayBhalani wait plz

Comment: @Salman your screenshot is not clear. i am not getting what you want exactly form your screen shot.

Comment: @JayBhalani please check the screenshot.... my device is iPad 3 and image size was 480 X 360 but my image stretched according to the UIImageView. I don't want this. Image should not be stretched no matter how much space would be empty around the Image.

Comment: @Salman please put your device screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
//set content mode
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//clear background color
self.imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

**UIViewContentMode**

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
```

Comment: This solution is implemented on UIImageView not UIImage.

Comment: @Salman i have tried it but works.. you can see the link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035523/how-to-make-image-not-stretching-in-uiimageview

Comment: @Salman Please share screen shot of your output and expected output.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have posted the screenshot. My Image size is 480 X 360 , my UIImageView resized according to iPad , but I don't want get my image resize or stretched.

Comment: @Salman have you seen the link which i have mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @AshokLondhe let me follow your post plz

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have seen the link you posted, and tried the "Centre"content mode for UIImageView. It sets my Image in the centre of the UIImageView and doesn't stretches the Image.

Comment: @AshokLondhe tell me how can I stretch my Image according to its width within the UIImageView ?

Comment: @Salman then no need to write above lines of code. remove it and try.

Comment: @AshokLondhe if Image is landscape it should strectched width wise and if the image is potrait then it should stretched height wise. this is what I want to achieve.   Keep it in mind that Image size would be 480 X 360.

Comment: @Salman try to add constraint to image view.. that is vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @AshokLondhe you mean do i need to use auto layout  constaraints or need to do something programatically

Comment: @AshokLondhe ok , thanks for your assistance and cooperation.

Comment: @Salman i have added .. vertical space constraint -top guide and horizontal space. and it works fine. you can do and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the `UIImage` to the `UIImageView` whose size is going to change. Add it to another `UIImageView` and make this second `UIImageView` a `subview` of the first `UIImageView`.

```
UIImage *exampleImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImageView *variableImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

CGFloat imageX = (variableImageView.bounds.size.width - exampleImage.size.width) / 2;
CGFLoat imageY = (variableImageView.bounds.size.height - exampleImage.size.height) / 2;

UIImageView *helperImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageX, imageY, exampleImage.size.width, exampleImage.size.height)];

helperImageView.image = exampleImage;
helperImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[self.view addSubview:variableImageView];
[variableImageView addSubview:helperImageView];
```

I hope this helps.